# Does Faker generate "real" UK Postcodes

Tags: python, faker

I am working out the best way to randomly generate test data. I need to generate a file the has UK Postcodes in it, however because I am then using these postcodes to cross reference with some real data I need to make sure the postcodes generated don't just match the expected UK postcode format, but are legitimate postcodes that really exist.

I know Faker can generate the correct format of data but am I right in thinking these are just randomly generated strings and therefore there is a high likelhood the postcodes generated will not match the real postcodes in my other data set?

Comment: At least in case of Finland I got 19248 which is not a legitimate postal code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postcodes that faker generates are randomly generated strings of the correct form, but there is no guarantee that the generated postcode corresponds to an actual place in the UK.

See the code for Faker's UK postcode generation [here](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/07ca4ede54c26554fdb5c7a4f55432cb0498d338/faker/providers/address/en_GB/__init__.py)

For example, the entry 'PN NEE' in the postcode_formats table could give rise to the postcode 'ZE0 0ZZ' but that does not (at time of writing) correspond to a place in the UK.